# How to subscribe event in datatemplate of listview

Tags: wpf, events, xaml, mvvm, command

In WPF I have a listview that is bound to an ObservableCollection.

XAML:

```
<ListView Name="listView" DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListOfOldData}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedOldData, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single">
        <ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
              <Button Content="Load" Command="{Binding Path=LoadCommand}"  Name="loadButton" Height="23" Width="75" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>             
              <!-- Is working just fine -->         
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock MouseLeftButtonDown="TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                           Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold"><TextBlock Text=" - " FontWeight="Normal"/><TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=UpdateDatum}" FontWeight="Normal"/></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

What I actually wanted to receive is a double-click on the selected-item. As I can't bind a command to a textblock in xaml (can I?) I tried doing this via the `MouseLeftButtonDown-Event`. But the event is never received!

C# (in code behind):

```
private void TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("MouseLeftButtonDown received!");
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I receive the event? Btw.: The command of the contextmenu is working just fine :)

**UPDATE** I found my error --> I added the event in the wrong usercontrol. Damn my missing concentration. Sorry for bugging you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListView` has a DoubleClick MouseEvent.
This should do it :

```
<ListView MouseDoubleClick="DoubleClickOnIt">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold">
            <TextBlock Text=" - " FontWeight="Normal"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=UpdateDatum}" FontWeight="Normal"/>
         </TextBlock>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>

   <ListViewItem>
      dddd
   </ListViewItem>
   <ListViewItem>
      eeeee
   </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

And the code behind :

```
private void DoubleClickOnIt(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   var listView = sender as ListView;
   var selectedItem = listView.SelectedItem;
   Console.WriteLine("received!");
}
```

Comment: That's not working for me. I don't know why, but it's never running in the event-handler.

Comment: I don't know what you have, I have it compiling and working here :)

Comment: Is there a possibility that it's a problem because my listview is in an Expander?

Comment: I just tried to put the listView in an Expander, still work fine.

Answer (score 3):

you can simply use InvokeCommandAction from blend sdk (System.Windows.Interactivity.dll)

```
    <ListView x:Name="lvw" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfOldData}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding Path=OpenCommand}" 
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=lvw, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    </ListView>
```

EDIT: 
viewmodel should look something like this:

```
    public List<object> ListOfOldData{ get; set; }

    private DelegateCommand<object> _openCommand;//or RelayCommand

    public DelegateCommand<object> OpenCommand
    {
        get { return _openCommand?? (this._openCommand= new DelegateCommand<object>(this.Execute)); }
    }

    private void Execute(object obj)
    {
        //obj is your selectedItem
    }
```

ps: dunno your type thats why object

Comment: But not working for me :(
The Command is not invoked. What is the possible problem? Any ideas?

Comment: any binding errors in your vs output window? if not you should post all relevant code from your viewmodel and view.

Comment: Oh - you haven't seen my update. I found my mistake, I used the wrong UserControl. Sorry for stealing your time!